# How can I remove an item from an ArrayList when it's data type is abstract?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, abstract-class

I'm new to Java so first of all sorry if this question is too stupid or something. I have an ArrayList of an abstract class. I added a few objects to the list. Now I need to remove one of them by finding it by one of its attributes. The thing is that the abstract class has two concrete classes and both of them were added to the list.  The attribute is inherited from the abstract class so when I do a foreach I do it with the abstract class, but I don't know how to tell it that the object it needs to remove is this concrete class and not the other one.

```
    public void removeFruit (Integer fruitCode) {
Apple lostFruit = null;
Banana lostFruit2 =null;
    for (Fruit fruit1 : fruitList) {
        if (fruit1.getFruitCode().equals(fruitCode) && fruit1 == Apple) {
            lostFruit = (Apple) fruit1;
            fruitList.remove(lostFruit);
        }else {
            lostFruit2 = (Banana) fruit1;
            fruitList.remove(lostFruit2);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(fruitCode + "has been removed from the list");

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know what concrete type it is, when the attribute you are looking for is in the abstract type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `Iterator` to accomplish that (which the `for-each` loop *hides*). As the [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) javadoc notes *the behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.*

```
Iterator<Fruit> iter = fruitList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Fruit f = iter.next();
    if (f.getFruitCode().equals(fruitCode)) {
        if (f instanceof Apple) {
            Apple a = (Apple) f;
            // ...
        } else if (f instanceof Banana) {
            Banana b = (Banana) f;
            // ...
        }
        iter.remove();
        System.out.println(fruitCode + " has been removed from the list");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would the while keep running until it finishes going through the entire list even though it may have already done what it was meant to do (remove the object)? Or would it stop once it finds the object and removes it?

Comment: @Nyom It would keep going. You didn't say `fruitCode` was unique. Add a `break` if it should stop after one match.

Comment: Sorry about that. In this case the break would go in the if clause or after the iter.remove(); ? (I don't use much the while statement so I'm unsure in this case where I should break it)

Comment: After the `iter.remove` inside the `if` on `fruitCode`. Also, if you're not doing anything else with `a` or `b`  you could remove those casts. It really wasn't clear why you wanted them in the first place.

Comment: I was told that the casts where needed since the foreach was running with an abstract class but my results needed to be a concrete class

Answer (score 2):

## No need to cast

> The attribute is inherited from the abstract class

No need to cast. When handling a `Fruit`, we do not care about `Apple` or `Banana`.

If the abstract class has what you need, you do not care about the concrete subclass. That is the point of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), not caring about the specific types when the more general type suffices.

```
public Fruit removeFruit (Integer fruitCode , List<Fruit> fruitList ) {

    for (Fruit fruit : fruitList ) {
        if ( fruit.getFruitCode().equals( fruitCode ) {
            fruitList.remove( fruit );
            return fruit ;
        }
    }
    return null ;  // In case you fruit code was not found.
}
```

Example usage:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = … ;
Integer fruitCode = … ;
Fruit fruitRemoved = this.removeFruit( fruitCode , fruits ) ;
System.out.println(
    "You deleted fruit code: " + fruitCode + " of type: " + fruitRemoved.getClass().getName() ;
)
```

> You deleted fruit code: 42 of type: Apple

---

In the example above, I would actually return [`Optional<Fruit>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) rather than `Fruit`. But that is a whole other discussion.

Comment: This one was my original solution but for some reason it didn't work out so I was trying another way (the one I presented here that I couldn't get it to run). I'll see if there were any other errors in my code that prevent this from working though all the other things did just like they were supposed to

Answer (score 0):

Check if fruit1 is instance of class Apple

```
if (fruit1 instanceof Apple) {
// your code
}
```